# MMS messages go into a group conversation with sender and my own number instead of the regular SMS conversation

Tags: sms, sim-card, mms

Let's say I have a conversation with Alice. If Alice sends me an MMS, it appears outside of that conversation, as a group conversation with Alice and my own phone number as participants. Could this be caused by having Unknown for My phone number in SIM status?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to set Your phone number to the actual phone number within advanced settings in Messaging.

Comment: Answering your own question is great, but it's important to use the same account. To get your two accounts merged, use the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page to ask SE staff directly.